# Spring RestTemplate GET: reading directories from Apache

Tags: spring, apache, rest, directory, spring-restcontroller

**apache serve**r is used for static contents. We are able to GET required resource having fully qualified path:(e.g. http://cmsTest.com/content/otp.txt). However, now we need to scan all folder available under

http://cmsTest.com/content

I need to access **directories** available at particular location via Spring REST GET api. When I am trying to access(http://cmsTest.com/content) it, getting 404 error.

Could you please provide suggestion for the same?

Comment: So, there is a REST API returning a list of directories, and you want to call that API? Whether it returns directories or anything else doesn't change how you use RestTemplate: you send a request, receive a response, containing a body, in a given format. Have you read the documentation? Tried anything?

Comment: Kindly provide more examples of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, I am trying to fetch name of directories using rest API. I have tried with getForObject. Couldn't got success

Comment: We can't possibly tell why unknown code calling an unknown API doesn't behave as you expect. Post the documentation of the API, and your code.

Comment: ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                    dirPath, String.class);

Comment: Getting 404 error: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found